# Search only blog posts on blog page

Tags: search

I would like a search box on the front page, where people can search for
anything thats is in the site and so on. And I would like an other one for
our blog.
Can we seperate the results? If someone search for a tour on the front
page, we don't want if she/he gets articles from our blog as a result. If
the user wants to read an article, than she/he has to use the search box on
the blog section

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `action` attribute of the form to search certain areas of your site. If your reading settings have separate front & post pages, you can set the `action` to the URL of the posts' page to search only the blog:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' ) ) ?>">
```

Alternatively, you can use hidden form inputs to set other query parameters like `post_type`, and then just use the site URL for the form action.

Comment: Thanks and where should i make those changes?